# \chapter* chapter name customisation in fncychap glenn

Tags: fncychap

I'm currently writing a book and I've decided to use the fncychap glenn style for my chapter headings. It's working great, but I was wondering if there's a way I could change the chapter name (eg. Chapter 1) in the top left hand corner to "Prologue".

[image: Example chapter title]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Prologue}
\chapter{Redundant Chapter}

\end{document}
```

So, in the case of what's above, where it says CHAPTER 1, I would like to say 'PROLOGUE', leaving the bottom open for whatever else I want (unconventional, I know. But it's in case I have other stuff I want to put in there later). I have an idea that I'd need to overwrite the \chNameVar but I'm not entirely sure of how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for us to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\makeatletter
%\ChNameVar{\Large\rmfamily}   %% earlier \Large\rm
%\ChNumVar{\Large}          %% earlier \Huge
%\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Prologue}
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \setlength{\py}{20pt}
    \setlength{\pyy}{\py}
    \setlength{\backskip}{\py}
    \addtolength{\backskip}{2pt}
    \addtolength{\pyy}{\RW}
    \setlength{\myhi}{\baselineskip}
    \addtolength{\myhi}{\pyy}
    \vskip 0.9\pyy
    {\Large\sffamily\MakeUppercase{ Prologue}}\space\mghrulefill{\RW}\rule[-1\py]{2\RW}{\pyy}\par\nobreak
    \vskip -0.8\backskip
    \rule{2\RW}{\myhi}\mghrulefill{\RW}\hskip 3pt %
    \raggedleft\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Prologue}
\chapter{Redundant Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought of the same, but i think the counter should vanish :-)

Comment: Oh my god, the code in `fncychap` is cruel.

Comment: Yeah, that's just about it. It just needs the number to go away.

Comment: Also, I only want it to apply on the \chapter* command (not the redundant chapter command, otherwise I need to renumber all of my other chapters.)

Comment: @dragnflier Like that?

Comment: How does the package chooses between normal and starred? I didn't see the switch.

Comment: @Johannes_B It is done via `\DOTIS` command. `\DOTI` is for regular chapter.

Comment: Yeah, i got that, but where is the decision to use `\DOTIS`?

Comment: @Johannes_B. It is there in the definition of `Glenn` → `\DeclareOption{Glenn}{....}`, line number 472 in the source code. :-)